# Why converting between time zones in Python yields different results?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have been working with time zones in Python for some time now. One of my challenges was creating an prize which was valid up to 23:59:59 **on the proper time zone** some days after the current time. I took the current UTC time, added a timedelta, converted to the desired time zone, replaced hour/minutes/seconds and converted back to UTC. That worked and still works perfectly.

Recently I tried to rewrite that code on another project and came to a situation which I cannot explain. Check out the example code below.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

dt1 = datetime\
.now(pytz.utc)\
.astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/Sao_Paulo"))\
.replace(
    year=2018,
    month=3,
    day=22,
    hour=23,
    minute=59,
    second=59,
    microsecond=0
)\
.astimezone(pytz.utc)

dt2=datetime(
    year=2018,
    month=3,
    day=22,
    hour=23,
    minute=59,
    second=59,
    microsecond=0,
    tzinfo=pytz.timezone("America/Sao_Paulo")
)\
.astimezone(pytz.utc)

print(dt1)
# 2018-03-23 02:59:59+00:00
print(dt2)
# 2018-03-23 03:05:59+00:00
```

Why `dt1 != dt2` ?

I know `dt1` is an ugly way to create a `datetime` object, but that is actually the value I expect. I cannot understand why they differ in 6 minutes.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the pytz documentation :

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.

Take a look at your dt2 before converting it to UTC and you'll see there's something fishy going on with its UTC offset:

```
>>> dt2 = datetime(year=2018, month=3, day=22,
...                hour=23, minute=59, second=59,
...                tzinfo=pytz.timezone("America/Sao_Paulo"))
>>> print(dt2)
2018-03-22 23:59:59-03:06
```

This on the other hand works:

```
>>> naive_dt = datetime(year=2018, month=3, day=22,
...                     hour=23, minute=59, second=59)
>>> aware_dt = pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo').localize(naive_dt)
>>> print(aware_dt)
2018-03-22 23:59:59-03:00
```

Comment: I could not find any of that on the docs I searched. That is actually a bug on the datetime constructors with time zones. Thank you very much for pointing it out!

Comment: Not trying to be rude or anything, but I'm curious why you couldn't find this in [the docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz) when it's in the note immediately after the package description at the very top of the introduction section, and then shows examples about 1 paragraph down from there.  Is there some other way the docs could highlight this better for you?